# Get form data in child component's to parent for submission

Tags: reactjs, forms

I was just wondering how I can Retrieve form data when a user submits I want to be able to see it in the console.log Here is what my parent component looks like. Please note: I am quite new to react....Thanks!

```
class App extends Component {

 render() {

   return (

      <div className="App">

      //Each component contains a seperate page with a form element
      <PageOne />

      <PageTwo />
      <PageThree />
      <PageFour />
      <PageFive />
      <PageSix />

      <Button>
         Submit Form
      </Button>

      <br/>
      <br/>



      </div>

   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Wheres the form at?

Comment: I just have my form within the child components

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of how this would work. You should pass in a function to the `onSubmit` property of a `form`. This function takes in an event object, which will have an array of all it's children in the `target` property. You can select the index of the fields you want the value of, which will be in the `value` property. In the example below, we are logging the value of the input.

```js
const onSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('event', event.target[0].value);
};

const SimpleForm = () => (
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleForm />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```